# Including global variables from main.cpp in LTexture class

Tags: c++, class, sdl-2

I've been following the Lazy Foo' tutorial on SDL2 and am on the section about color keying (https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/10_color_keying/index.php). The tutorial creates a new class that removes the cyan from an image and renders it.

In the tutorials source code the author declares the class in main, but I'm using separate LTexture.cpp and LTexture.h files for organization. The issue is that my SDL renderer, gRenderer, is undefined in the LTexture class. What can I do in order to include gRenderer in LTexture.cpp?

Some additional information: I am working with precompiled headers, and use pch.h for includes and predeclarations. Also I'm pretty new to C++, so let me know if there's anything I should be doing to improve my code.

gRenderer is defined above int main() like so:

SDL_Renderer* gRenderer = NULL;

And here is LTexture.cpp:

```
#include "LTexture.h"

LTexture::LTexture()
{
    //Initialize
    mTexture = NULL;
    mWidth = 0;
    mHeight = 0;
}

LTexture::~LTexture()
{
    //Deallocate
    free();
}

bool LTexture::loadFromFile(std::string path)
{
    //Get rid of preexisting texture
    free();

    //Final texture
    SDL_Texture* newTexture = NULL;

    //Load image from path
    SDL_Surface* loadedSurface = IMG_Load(path.c_str());

    //Color key image
    SDL_SetColorKey(loadedSurface, SDL_TRUE, SDL_MapRGB(loadedSurface->format, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF));

    //Transfer pixels from surface to texture
    newTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, loadedSurface);

    //Get image dimensions
    mWidth = loadedSurface->w;
    mHeight = loadedSurface->h;

    //Get rid of old oaded surface
    SDL_FreeSurface(loadedSurface);

    //Return success
    mTexture = newTexture;
    return newTexture != NULL;
}

void LTexture::free()
{
    //Free texture if it exists
    if (mTexture != NULL)
    {
        SDL_DestroyTexture(mTexture);
        mTexture = NULL;
        mWidth = 0;
        mHeight = 0;
    }
}

void LTexture::render(int x, int y)
{
    //Set rendering space and render to screen
    SDL_Rect renderQuad = { x, y, mWidth, mHeight };
    SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, mTexture, NULL, &renderQuad);
}

int LTexture::getWidth()
{
    return mWidth;
}

int LTexture::getHeight()
{
    return mHeight;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't - anything you want to include/use across different files needs to be in a separate file from main. You can make a class.cpp/class.hpp pair, and #include the .hpp where you require it

Comment: If you have global variable shared between multiple translation units, you declare it in each unit with `extern SDL_Renderer* gRenderer;` (i.e. in your `LTexture.cpp`) and define it without `extern` in single unit.

Comment: @benroberts999 The main file is not special. Nothing stops you from making a header for it.